# Run an ftp batch file from within a batch file

Tags: command-line, batch, ftp

I have a scheduled task which executes the commands in my file ftp.txt every day. The file can be seen below, it connects via ftp to my site and puts 3 XML files on to my web server.

command:

```
ftp -s:filename
```

File executed by command

```
open ftp.mysite.co.uk
username
password
put C:\file.xml location/file.xml
put C:\file1.xml location/file1.xml
put C:\file2.xml location/file2.xml
bye
```

I now have to execute the same transfers but to sites with different ftp details. I don't want to schedule a new windows task for each transfer so i was wondering if there is a way to execute other ftp.txt files from the main ftp.txt file that is triggered from the command line?
If that is not possible could i just run several ftp batch files from a single command line command.

Comment: you wrote "I think i may have found a simpler way. I should just be able to extend the ftp.txt file i have. Replacing "bye" with "close" and then starting another ftp session straight after, this way i can use different ftp details and upload the files in different place" <--  post that as an answer then

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) as [scripted FTP client](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#script_file).

Scripting functionality of `WinSCP` does not support any control sequences, manipulation of file paths, etc. If you need these, you have to call WinSCP script from a wrapper script implemented in another scripting language (like [VBscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)). Any language which supports [COM/ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) can be used.

[Example](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_com_wsh#vbscript) from the WinSCP site:

```
<job>
<reference object="WinSCP.Session" />
<script language="VBScript">

Option Explicit

' Setup session options
Dim sessionOptions
Set sessionOptions = WScript.CreateObject("WinSCP.SessionOptions")
With sessionOptions
    .Protocol = Protocol_Sftp
    .HostName = "example.com"
    .UserName = "user"
    .Password = "mypassword"
    .SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 1024 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
End With

Dim session
Set session = WScript.CreateObject("WinSCP.Session")

' Connect
session.Open sessionOptions

' Upload files
Dim transferOptions
Set transferOptions = WScript.CreateObject("WinSCP.TransferOptions")
transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode_Binary

Dim transferResult
Set transferResult = session.PutFiles("d:\toupload\*", "/home/user/", False, transferOptions)

' Throw on any error
transferResult.Check

' Print results
Dim transfer
For Each transfer In transferResult.Transfers
    WScript.Echo "Upload of " & transfer.FileName & " succeeded"
Next

' Disconnect, clean up
session.Dispose

</script>
</job>
```

Modify such a script to take care of your specific/dynamic needs.

Comment: I think i may have found a simpler way. I should just be able to extend the ftp.txt file i have. Replacing "bye" with "close" and then starting another ftp session straight after, this way i can use different ftp details and upload the files in different places.

Comment: True. But you can also use Scheduler to call single batch file, which would then launch all the required FTP sessions. Such approach will be easier to manage, it may also allow you to launch concurrent sessions with 'start' command, were there such need and the files large.

Comment: Have in mind that FTP automations typically need some error checking. A linear script either works or fails. If you start dozens of scripts, it could be very hard to find what went wrong. Another potential problem is security. The FTP protocol transmits passwords in clear text without encryption. That can be avoided using SFTP.